# Error in switch() case;

Tags: javascript, jquery

While I'm trying to write a simple function which need to iterate through classes of event.target and do something depending of class name, I've encountered unknown error (as for me).

```
function tPager() {
    var lc = $(event.target).attr('class');
    swith(lc) {
        case ('slow'): 
            console.log('slowclicked'); 
            break;
        case ('page'): 
            console.log('pageclicked'); 
            break;
    }
};
```

This is just for testing purposes, console will always say "Unexpected token", there is an error in line 3, "{". Can't get what's wrong.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2cJhC/

Comment: You write `swith` instead of `switch`.

Comment: Yeah, right... Don't know why I didn't noticed that. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe change your text editor, you'd seen the mistake sooner with a good syntaxic coloration (or even better a live code checker).

Comment: @Holt also code autocompletion helps to eradicate a lot of such errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wouldn't the code be like this

```
switch(lc) { // note the keyword switch
   case 'slow': 
      console.log('slowclicked'); 
      break;
   case 'page': 
      console.log('pageclicked'); 
      break;
}
```

You're currently having this

```
swith(lc) { // that is not switch keyword.
```

The mistake actual, was at the keyword usage. You were having the wrong keyword that was triggering the mistake. Change it, and its good to go!